# What websites do you visit for gaining sharepoint related knowledhge

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Every morning I came in office and everyday look for information about sharepoint, I also come here.So which are the websites you visit frequently as a SharePoint developer, admin or end user to stay updated.

Comment: Personnaly, this site is the first thing I open every morning, looking for thread I can understand (cause I'm not a dev at all), answering if I can, and looking at links people provide.  Remember to use the search tool, and "tags".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of my favorites (besides this site):

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/